# Trajectory in 2d on android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to create a game similar to paper toss.
(main idea is: 2d game that the user will throw a ball on the z axis - inside the screen).

my problem is how create the movement (trajectory) of  the ball.
I did a bit of de-compiling of the game toss-it and I found that they are not using any engines or openGL but I couldn't find the way how they did the movement.

Maybe you know any example for this or advise how to do this (canvas tricks, SurfaceView ...)

I'm new in Android field so I might have a lack of basic info.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt and Android thing its a maths thing. Your ball will fall at the speed of "gravity" the standard formulas are below. If you google equations of motion you should be able to get some examples =)

v = u + at where v = final speed, u = initial speed, a = acceleration and t= times
s = ut + 0.5at^2 where s = displacement

Comment: you right with the formula, but how to draw this, just calculate the point and re-size the ball according the z axis ? Maybe there is something that build in that i should use.